# Objective C: What format to use when declaring a NSString message to include a NSDate Object?

Tags: objective-c, datetime, date, nsstring, datepicker

I have included a Date Picker in my application and am trying to dispay the message "You have selected Date and Time XXX" after clicking on a button. How to I initialize my message so that the dates are showing correctly? My code snippet as below:

```
NSDate *selected = [datePicker date]; 
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"The date and time you selected is: %@", selected];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date and Time Selected"
                                                message:message delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes, I did."
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show];

[alert release]; 
[message release];
```

My alert message is now showing my 'null' instead of the exact date and time I require. Can you advise what is required before the alert can display the date and time correctly?

Thanks alot

Zhen Hoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter to obtain a string representation of your date.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; // Modify this to your liking
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter release];
```